# Weird behaviour of console.log() in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var foo = {
a : function(){
    console.log(this)
},

b : console.log(this)
}

foo.a()
```

Output :-
    `{}`
`{ a: [Function: a], b: undefined }`

`foo` variable is first declared and hence the key `b` is evaluated, giving us the global object through `console.log()` :- It displays `{}` in node and `Window` in browser

However, when `foo.a()` is called, `b` shows `undefined`

Am I missing some concept? Why isn't it evaluated again?

Thank you

Comment: I’m not sure what you expect. The return value of `console.log(this)` is `undefined`. That’s why `b` is always `undefined`.

Comment: Hi @Xufox I expected it to return `{}` like it did the first time instead of `undefined` . Refer to the details I added in the edits, sorry missed out the output (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a foo object, and you assign it two properties:

- You set `a` be a function with the text `function(){console.log(this)}`
- You set `b`to be the return value from `console.log(this)`. console.log(this) gets executed immediately, and logs out the object. The object hasn't been given its properties yet, so it logs out `{}`. The return value of console.log() is `undefined`, so `b` gets set to `undefined`.

You've now initialized your object, with a = some function and b = undefined. Later, when you call a, it logs out the foo object, with a = some function, and b = undefined.

Comment: Hi @Nicholas Tower, Oh! I get it now! Thanks! (: